# Python Regex: obtaining currency numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and am trying to use re.findall to extract currency-like numbers (integers or floats with 1 or 2dp) from strings of the form:

```
'1000 - 2000' , '1000 -', '1000.4'
```

I have struggled to find a regex pattern that would allow me to extract all numbers from the strings into a separate list, and would appreciate any help on this matter.

For example,

```
import re

pattern = '^\d*[.,]?\d*$'
temp = ['1000.5 - 2000.55']
strings = re.findall('^\d*[.,]?\d*$', temp[0])
```

The output I get is an empty list , []

I would like to obtain

```
strings = ['1000.5','2000.55']
```

and then would like to convert them to floats with

```
nums = [float(i) for i in strings]
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output? Your question will be considered *too broad* otherwise.

Comment: Do you want floats with 1 decimal point as well?

Comment: Also, when you say `with 2dp` do you mean if you have a number like `1.123` you want to get `1.12` or you want to disregard it completely such that you don't have it show up in the output? Also if you have `1.126`, assuming you want to cut off the last digits such that you get `1.12`: Do you want `1.12` or the rounded value of `1.13`?

Comment: Apologies for the poorly framed question. I would like to consider numbers with 1 dp but would like to completely disregard numbers with more than 2 dp. So that a number like 1.126 isn't extracted from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
temp = ['1000.5 - 2000.55']
final_data = map(float, re.findall('\d+\.\d+|\d+', temp[0]))
```

Output:

```
[1000.5, 2000.55]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

temp = ['1000.5 - 2000.55']
strings = re.findall('\d+(?:[.,]\d*)?', temp[0])
nums = [float(i) for i in strings]
print(nums) # [1000.5, 2000.55]
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/926342)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `[0-9.]+` :

```
import re
pattern=r'[0-9.]+'
temp = ['1000.5 - 2000.55']
for i in temp:
    print(list(map(lambda x:float(x),re.findall(pattern,i))))
```

output:

```
[1000.5, 2000.55]
```

You can also do in one line :

```
print([list(map(lambda x:float(x),re.findall(pattern,i))) for i in temp][0])
```

output:

```
[1000.5, 2000.55]
```